# Is PCA good choice to reduce data dimensionality in this case?

Tags: pca, svm, feature-selection

I have an emotion database of 213 (with 7 classes). I used a bank of Gabor filters for the extraction of features. So I got a data matrix of **213x50000 (a huge number of parameters on only 213 images !!)**. So i have to reduce this large number of features before learning with SVM, and i decided to reduce with PCA. Is it a good choice?

Comment: use Convolutional neural network instead of PCA + SVM

Comment: but i would used Gabor filter not deep learning approach